# How to make a shadow for png or svg drawable along the contour?

Tags: android, svg, png, shadow

It is necessary to drop the shadow from the view element. There is a picture in svg and png format. But it is impossible to do this correctly.
Option without shadow:[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wu5Ay.png)
The option with the shadow that you need to get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C74D9.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to just use this image as a background image, with the shadow already in it, and add an amount of padding to all sides equal to the size of the cutout so you don't draw over it